# Overriding Field Collection output

Tags: theming, entities

I have a content type named: `lectures`

In this content type I have a field collection field named: `field_course_video_slide_sync`

This field collection consists of 3 fields: `field_start_slide_sec`, `field_slide_title` and `field_slide_number`

What I'm trying to achieve is to rewrite them into this:

```
<ul>
 <li begin="field_start_slide_sec"><a href="#field_slide_number">field_slide_title</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried `tpl.php`, `preprocess_node`, `field_get_items` and [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) but nothing seems to work. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override **field-collection-item.tpl.php** file present in the [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module directory. You can put your code in that. Just simply copy it to your theme folder, and place the code inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I've created a file in my theme folder **field-collection-item--field-course-video-slide-sync.tpl.php** and wrapped the items in an '<ul>' but how can I format the 3 fields in this field collection from that tpl file?

Comment: Ok, So I hope your tpl is get called. Now we have a variable in it as **$content**. So you can check the content in that and print that according to you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If anyone else wanted to know, here is what I did: I created a **field-collection-item--field-course-video-slide-sync.tpl.php** with only **<?php print render($content); ?>** in it. And did the field theming in **field--field-start-slide-sec--field-course-video-slide-sync.tpl.php**, **field--field-slide-title--field-course-video-slide-sync.tpl.php** and **field--field-slide-number--field-course-video-slide-sync.tpl.php**.